# CMake Error in ROS Navigation

Tags: navigation, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I followed these steps to install ROS navigation:

```
 cd catkin_ws/src
 git clone https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git
 cd ..
 catkin_make
```

but I have this error

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:283 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:337 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  navigation/robot_pose_ekf/CMakeLists.txt:6 (pkg_check_modules)
```

What does it mean? How do I fix? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228076/cmake-error-in-ros-navigation/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been asked before.

A quick search leads to [Installing package from source in Indigo](http://answers.ros.org/question/208963/installing-package-from-source-in-indigo/) for instance. Be sure to change the appropriate parts of the answer (github url, package names, etc).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-03**:
I solved my problem. Thank you!

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-03-06**:
Hi! I commented on this link
http://answers.ros.org/question/208963/installing-package-from-source-in-indigo/
because I have another problem. If such a question has already been done, can you show me the solution found? Thank you.